# Why is my python program writing debug level log even though I set the level to warning?

Tags: python

My code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = logging.getLogger('Run')
    try:
        hostname = socket.gethostname()
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,  
                            format=hostname+" %(asctime)s: %(name)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s",
                            filename=PATH_TO_LOGFILE,
                            filemode='a')

        consolelog = logging.StreamHandler()
        consolelog.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(levelname)-8s: %(message)s"))
        logging.getLogger('').addHandler(consolelog)
        logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        logging.getLogger("kazoo").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

...
```

What I want for this code is to write logs at debug level, but not for requests and kazoo modules.

But this program prints logs like:

```
DEBUG   : Starting new HTTPS connection (1): knox.MYURL:443
```

Isn't this a log for a request module?

Why is this written?

Answer (score 0):

```
DEBUG   : Starting new HTTPS connection (1): knox.MYURL:443
```

Does NOT have the logger name after `DEBUG` - that's the first thing to notice to know which logger is printing this.

The log is printed by the root logger, while you have set the logger named requests and kazoo to WARNING, root is set to DEBUG with `logging.BasicConfig(..)`.

```
import socket
import requests
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('Run')
hostname = socket.gethostname()
PATH_TO_LOGFILE = './test.log'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format=hostname+" %(asctime)s: %(name)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s",
                    filename=PATH_TO_LOGFILE,
                    filemode='a')
logging.getLogger('').setLevel(logging.INFO)
consolelog = logging.StreamHandler()
consolelog.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(levelname)-8s: %(message)s"))
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(consolelog)
logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger("kazoo").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

requests.get('http://google.com')
```

In the code snippet above - `logging.getLogger('').setLevel(logging.INFO)` sets the root logger to INFO and you won't see the messages.

Comment: I need other modules to print logs at debug level. Your code seems to change the log level globally to INFO. I want to apply a different log level ONLY for requests and kazoo.